# extract certain text from an image using OCR

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, ocr

want to extract the drug name ONLY from the label (heading) using OCR tesseract

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
im = Image.open("sample1.jpg")
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(im, lang = 'eng')
print(text)
```

[image]

I want it to recognize the drug name automatically with out using positioning and return

```
glimepiride
```

what should i add to the code??

Comment: Do some research, it should not be so hard. Some basic pre-processing should reduce the difficult of this task..

Comment: Does the name always appear in the same region?

Comment: @NicEndo i'm using tesseract, found the bounding boxes function, but not the LARGEST bounding box. would you help me with the code, please?

Comment: @fredguth no , it differs from one drug to another would it be possible to extract the drug name only?? is there a function to extract text with the largest font size in the image?

Comment: @NicEndo if i found something i wouldn't be here asking, been searching, trying and failing for 2 months , and came here for an answer.

Comment: How do you define  *drug name* ? Is it among a list of candidate names ? Is it the string with the biggest bounding box ? Or do you have a single type of drug to process ?

Comment: @GabrielDevillers  the string with the biggest bounding box since most of the drug names are written bigger than the rest of the other info in the box.

Comment: Then you should add to your question the code that you have tried to use to extract the biggest bounding box, or add what function you are missing from pytesseract.

Comment: @GabrielDevillers i did not write a code for it. i asked how to, then one recommended using biggest bounding box. which i know nothing about. and i want to use it as an input to the tesseract function above.

Comment: hi Hoor did you find any solution I'am facing same problem

Comment: @Kpatel hi, i'm sorry i didn't find a solution (":